# How to write a function that turns a float into an int and rounds it up instead of down(which is the usual response python gives)

Tags: python-3.x

Write a function that takes a float as input and rounds it away from zero, i.e., returns the integer obtained
by rounding up for positive floats and by rounding down for negative floats. The return value should always
be an int object. Consider the example below.

```
>>> round_away_from_zero(7.2)
8
>>> round_away_from_zero(-3.6)
-4
>>> round_away_from_zero(5.0)
5
```

Is there a simple iteration that I can solve using this.
I understand it has to do with floor division(i.e x//2) but not sure how to implement

Comment: try `math.ceil()`

Comment: Your title says "up", but the question body says "away from zero". Those are different things.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IF statement. If the number is positive, then we use `math.ceil()`. Otherwise, we use `math.floor()`.

```
def round_away_from_zero(n):
    if n > 0: 
        return math.ceil(n)
    else: 
        return math.floor(n)
```

Comment: this is a reasonable answer, but I urge you to follow PEP8 style guidlines with regards to indentation, and also, your `return 0` is unreachable, and should be removed (if you had formatted your code conventionally this would have been more obvious!)

Comment: I took the liberty of making the edits.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga it might be even better to leave out the `else` entirely and let the function end on a `return`.